# Calculate the parabolic ripple left by dragging an object over a liquid surface?

Tags: trigonometry

i'm trying to simulate the parabolic ripple left by dragging an object over a liquid surface. 
I can't seem to find anything on this subject... actually i have no clue what to look for or the how to describe the physics and math behind this in the right way.

I read up on how to create and drag around Parabola's, but i would like to know the right way to calculate a simulation, not just fake the effect.

a pointer would be great, an answer would be awesome.
i hope this belongs here and not on a physics forum?, sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: Actually I would have said the reverse? I'm also a newbie in those kind of topics, but I'm tempted to say the actual shape of the ripple depends on the properties of your fluid. Then again, maybe those properties don't have that much influence on the shape over the surface, but only impact the admissible speed of drag and height of the ripple?

Comment: I don't see why it should be parabolic.  In principle, one might expect (in the frame of reference of the liquid) the disturbances caused by the object at a certain point to travel outward at a constant speed from that point.  If the object is moving at constant speed, this would result in straight-line ripples.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake#Kelvin_wake_pattern

Comment: @Chappers Great! thanks, just what i was looking for!